# Need to use of concurrency in this java method

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, concurrency

So I have the following code that takes the input of two arrays, and apply some queries to match elements from `Array1` with elements from `Array2`, then it returns the number of elements that are similar in the two ArrayLists.

Here is the code I use:

```
    public static void get_ND_Matches() throws IOException{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    array1 = new ArrayList<String>( ClassesRetrieval.getDBpediaClasses());
    array2 = new ArrayList<String>( ClassesRetrieval.fileToArrayListYago());
    String maxLabel="";
    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    int number;     
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> theMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(String yagoClass:array2){
        theMap.put(yagoClass, getListTwo(yagoClass));
        System.out.println("Done for : "+yagoClass );
    }       
    for(String dbClass:array1){
        ArrayList<String> result = get_2D_Matches(dbClass);
        for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : theMap.entrySet()){
            String yagoClass=entry.getKey();
            Set<String> IntersectionSet =Sets.intersection(Sets.newHashSet(result), Sets.newHashSet(entry.getValue()));
            System.out.println(dbClass + " and "+ yagoClass+ " = "+ IntersectionSet.size());
            number = IntersectionSet.size();
            map.put(yagoClass, number);
        }   
        int maxValue=(Collections.max(map.values()));
        for(Entry<String, Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getValue()==maxValue && maxValue != 0){
                 maxLabel = entry.getKey();
            }
            if(maxValue==0){
                maxLabel = "Nothing in yago";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println(dbClass+" from DBPEDIA Corresponds to "+ maxLabel);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        
    }
}
```

This code returns for example:

> Actor from DBPEDIA Corresponds to Yago_Actor
>
> Album from DBPEDIA Corresponds to Yago_Album
>
> SomeClass from DBPEDIA Corresponds to nothing in Yago

Etc..

Behind the scenes, this code uses `getDBpediaClasses` and then applies `Get_2D_Matches();` method to get an arrayList of results for each class. Each ArrayList resulted is then compared to another ArrayList generated by `getListTwo()` for each class of `fileToArrayListYago()`.

Now, because of all the calculations made in the background (there are millions of elements  in each array), this process takes hours to execute.

I would really like to use **concurrency/multithreading** to solve this issue. Could anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: Oracle can show you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ :)

Comment: Java 8 [parallel streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) and lambdas could help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It makes little sense to parallelize code which is not perfectly clean and optimized. You may get factor 4 on a typical 4-core CPU or nothing at all, depending on whether you choose the part to be paralellized properly. Use of a better algorithm may give you much more.

It's possible that the bottleneck is `get_2D_Matches`, which you haven't published.

Computing the maximum directly instead of creating a throw-away `HashMap<String,Integer> map` could save quite some time, and so could moving `Sets.newHashSet(result)` out of the loop.

You should really reconsider variable naming. With names like `map`, `theMap`, and `result` (for something which is not the method's result), it's hard to find out what's going on.

If you really want to parallelize it, you need to split your overlong method first. Then it's rather simple as the processing of each `dbClass` can be done independently. Just encapsulate it as a `Callable` and submit it to an `ExecutorService`.

However, I'd suggest to clean the code first, then submit it to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), and then consider parallelizing it.